# How to get all the features of Oh My Zsh on all users?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

The trouble is that I lose all the features of Oh My Zsh (powerlevel10k, zsh-autosuggestions, zsh-syntax-highlighting) when I switch to another user as superuser `sudo su` or postgres user `sudo su postgres`.

I am using ubuntu `20.04`, zsh `5.8` and the last version of oh my zsh.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo zsh` and `sudo -u postgres zsh` instead of `sudo su` and `sudo su postgres`.